# "IndexError: string index out of range" when inserting CSV file to SQL Database PYTHON

Tags: python, sql, pandas, csv, execute

I have this code to upload a CSV file "latest_file" that has 7 columns and looks like this:

Date,   Full Name,  hour30, email,  Role,   Aux_code,   Adjusted State Timev2
3/5/2020,   Rolando Cardona,    23:30:00,   rolandoc@email.com, Tier 2, Unavailable,    0.466666667
3/5/2020,   Allan Moncada,  23:00:00,   allanm@email.com,   Tier 1, Unavailable,    0.016666667
3/5/2020,   Angel Alonzo,   23:00:00,   angela3@email.com,  Tier 1, Unavailable,    0.05
3/5/2020,   David Lobo, 23:30:00,   davidl2@email.com,  Tier 1, On Call,    0
3/5/2020,   Sandra Cerrato, 23:00:00,   sandrac@email.com,  Tier 2, After Call Work,    6.25
3/5/2020,   Erick Flores,   23:00:00,   erickf@email.com,   0,  do not use - UNAVAILABLE, 178.6333333
3/5/2020,   Diego Cerrato,  23:00:00,   diegoc@email.com,   Tier 1, Ready,  58.83333333

to my data base with this code:

```
for row in latest_file:
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO V6_test (Date,Full_Name,hour30,email,Role,Aux_code,Adjusted_Time)
                  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);''', row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6])
```

Im reading latest file with

```
latest_file = pd.read_csv(#filepath, sep = ",")
```

but i'm getting this error code "IndexError: string index out of range"
some values in Role were NULL
so I tried to fill those up with a 0
To see if the NULLs where causing the issue but with no luck

To check the value type of each row i did:

```
for row in latest_file:
print('TYPE:', type(row))
    print('ROW', row)
```

but for some reason all types came as string for each row even after formatting each column with:

```
latest_file['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(latest_file["Date"], format = '%m/%d/%y')
latest_file['hour30'] = pd.to_datetime(latest_file['hour30'],format='%H:%M').dt.time
latest_file['Adjusted State Timev2'] = latest_file['Adjusted State Timev2'].astype(float)
```

I get the same error and still type string for all columns
I also changed all data types on the data base table to string just to see, but with no luck

Any ideas?

Comment: a `for` loop like that is only iterating over the column names, not the rows. Use [`iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) ie `for idx, row in latest_file.iterrows():`

Comment: That worked for me thanks a lot!!